# Is it mandatory to register a business account at online shops?

Tags: business, germany

I have a small computer business.
I order about 5 devices (printers/SSDs/notebooks/...) total  for my clients a month in different online stores.

On many online stores you can register as private person (consumer) or business customer.
Private persons have different conditions.

Examples are Amazon and eBay.

Is it mandatory to register as business customer?
Or is it ok to use a private account?

Comment: Which country? Or would you be happy with an answer that is correct in Senegal?

Comment: No :-) I thought it's maybe the same for all countries. Germany.

Comment: in an EU context, buying devices as a business can have VAT-related advantages. Within Germany: you still pay full price, but you get a proper invoice that you can use to deduct the paid VAT from the VAT that you owe for your own sales. Between EU countries: due to the reverse-charge mechanism, you do not have to pay VAT to the seller at the source country VAT rates (→ you get a cheaper price). Instead, you have to pay the VAT at your own country's VAT rates directly to your own Finanzamt.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Don't use a private account.**

There are some issues with the VAT (see amon's comment). In addition the (European) consumer protection law doesn't apply on you. Because of that, the shops don't want you to use a consumer account.

If there are no problems no one will gripe, but if there are problems (defect devices etc.) the shop may notice you weren't a consumer and this may impair your position. In the end you may not get the consumer rigths but also not the better parts of buisiness contract.

In addition if your lie causes a pecuniary loss for the shop, it may be fraud (§ 263 StGB) or computer fraud (§ 263a StGB).

The other way around (consumer with buisiness account) it isn't OK, too.